# Django query without extra or Raw

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to write a query such as

```
`Select * from my_table where 'parameter1' LIKE CONCAT("%", col_1, "%") 
OR 'parameter2' LIKE CONCAT("%", col_1, "%") AND (col_2 IS NULL OR 'parameter3' LIKE CONCAT ("%", col_2, "%") AND (col_3 IS NULL OR col_3='parameter4')`.
```

I have been trying out the following.

```
first_partial_qs = ModelName.extra(where=["%s LIKE CONCAT ('%%', col_1, '%%')"],params=[something1])
first_final_qs = first_partial_qs | ModelName.extra(where=["%s LIKE CONCAT ('%%', col_1, '%%')"],params=[something2])
second_qs = ModelName.filter(col_2__isnull=True) | ModelName.extra(where=["%s LIKE CONCAT ('%%', col_2, '%%')"], params=[something3])
third_qs = ModelName.filter(Q(col_3__isnull=True) | Q(col_3=something4))
```

I want to know how would I do 
    `final_qs = first_final_qs AND second_qs AND third_qs`

But since life is not that simple (for django developers since they will be deprecating `extra()`, I want to find a way to do it without using `extra()`. One option would be to use `raw()` but is there a more Django-ish way of doing this?